# How to manipulate value of a inner EditText by a inner Button.setOnClickListener

Tags: android, class, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a extend ArrayAdapter Class that in the getView function inflate for every listitem a layout with a EditText and Button I need that  when Button is pressed the value of EditText get incremented, Iam trying this with this code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View item = convertView;
        if (item == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_clientes, null);
        }

        TextView p = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.txtProd);
        Button bMas = (Button)item.findViewById(R.id.btnMas);
        Button bMen = (Button)item.findViewById(R.id.btnMenos);

        EditText txtCant = (EditText) item.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidad);
        bMas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Integer n = 0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                n++;
                txtCant.setText(String.valueOf(n));//ERROR (txtCant)
            }
        });

        p.setText(datosProd.get(position).getProducto());
        return item;
    }
```

but this give an error: "variable txtCant is accessed from within inner class needs to be declareted final" if I do this (declarete fina) I can't use setText. How I resolve this?

Comment: check out view holder pattern for list view adapter

Comment: member of a inner class or outter classs? if a outter class dont work when increment the value of EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to increment the count for each of the grid item, have a global variable somewhere and increment that everytime a button is pressed for a corresponding position.

E.g.

`Config.java file:`

Declare a variable here for each of item(If you know how many items are going to be populated).

```
    public class Config {


    public static final int countItem1=0;
    public static final int countItem2=0;
    public static final int countItem2=0;
}
```

Now on onClick for button, check the position and corresponding value and increment it.

E.g.

```
    @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch(position)
                   {
                         case 0:
                         int n=Config.countitem1;
                         txtCant.setText(String.valueOf(n+1);
                         Config.countItem1++;
                         break;
                         .....


                         .....
                   }
                }
            });
```

Or,you could simply onItemClickListener of grid and apply the logic there. Make items in grid as `focusable=false`.

**Edit:**

Am adding a sampple adapter class which extends BaseAdapter.
I added your variable names and all. Let me know if it works.

```
public class CustomListAdapterList extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<xyz> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;
    boolean state;
    public CustomListAdapterRList(Context aContext, ArrayList<xyz> listData) {

        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = aContext;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View v=convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_dish_single, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.p = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtProd);
                holder.txtCant = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidad);
                holder.bMen = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMas);
                holder.bMas = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMenos);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.bMas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                state=holder.bMas.isSelected();

                if(!state) {
                        int n=Integer.valuesOf(holder.txtCant.getText().toString().trim());
                        holder.txtCant.setText(String.valueOf(n+1));


                }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView p;
        EditText txtCant ;
        Button bMas ;
        Button bMen;
    }
}
```

Comment: in this scope txtCant is not accessesible and I dont know thes total items in list

Comment: You got 2 Buttons,1 textview and one edittext in the custom gridview. Right? And why do you want that to be edittext if you are auto incrementing the value in it.

Comment: I need that when the user press the button "+" inc the value of EditText and when press the button  "-" decrease his value, I am using a Listview